# Canonical MAAS with multiple VLAN's

Tags: ubuntu, openstack, openstack-neutron, openstack-horizon, juju

Regarding networking setup with Canonical MAAS. I got MAAS 1.9.3 running and have deployed Openestack. Got VM’s running and all that seems to be working. However i have decided that i would like to now route another IP range to the servers. I then added a network and a router for the new network.

Here is a question or two, how do i add additional VLAN to the setup and doing it without having to rebuild a whole environment?

Second question is, after i added a VLAN i realised that the ports for a public network where nodes are plugged in are not trunk ports. I changed that and added more VLAN’s but obviously since i have VLAN tagging now i cannot reach any of the perviously reachable VM instance’s. Is there a way to setup VLAN tagging in MAAS to the nodes? And going back to a previous question what if in 6 months i want to add another VLAN with another different IP range would i be experiencing the same problem?

To add a bit more info to this i am running Autopilot with MAAS.

Comment: Anyone have any ideas how to tag VLANS inside Canonical MAAS?

Comment: I have a very similar problem, with no solution yet.  My ports are trunk ports, and adding VLANs results in the MAAS node being inaccessible.

As for reconfiguration, you cannot do that through MAAS without deploying the system again.  You can ssh into the node and alter the networking configuration manually.

Comment: Ok i have worked it out but i dont have all the answers, basically you have to use maas-cli not the webui. First you have to login into mass. Check what fabrics are in place maas 19-root fabrics read then create new vlans maas 19-root vlans create 0 name="Storage network" vid=100 for example and than last thing is to create a subnet that goes to the vlan maas 19-root subnets create cidr=192.168.24.0/23 vlan=your vlan id that you saw from previous output

Comment: What version of MAAS are you using?  I think you can do all of these steps through the web UI, but some menu options don't exist on certain pages/steps of the process.

Comment: I am using 1.9.4 at the moment. I am planing to use autopilot and auto pilot does not work in maas 2.0. I am also on 14.04LTS on my maas

Answer (score 0):

To create vlans in MAAS use the MAAS CLI:

```
maas my-maas vlans create 5 name="Mgmt network" vid=120
maas my-maas subnet update 6 vlan=5006
```

The values will be different for your case.